# Enable My Background Service Notification Pragmatically

Tags: android, background-service

I'm having android application that i have to run in background using services for android o and above i know that background services are killed by system so i'm using **`startForground`** with proper notifications but sometimes these notification do not appear and it may be because of mobile settings

so if we go from

> Settings->App->My App Name->Notifications->My Background Services &
>   Services

hence my question is how do i start or check these My Background Services & Services pragmatically.

Answer (score 1):

From Android O,

**We need to set channel id for each notification arrived in background.**

> [You can check latest firebase implementation here.](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android)

In manifest need to add

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="default_channel_id"/>
```

And in your Messaging service class,

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
     sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());//Considering you have message in your body.
    }
```

And

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response but that is not my question, my question is how Settings->App->My App Name->Notifications->My Background Services & Services check these two pragmatically

Comment: I don't think so, that background service is permission based in android. Please share any link or logic related your question.

Comment: **I know, from version greater than Android O (26), documentation suggesting that use schedule job instead of background service.** But in case of FCM not mentioned any kind of permission module related  to background message service implementation. **If you suggest any logic or scenario in that case I can help you and I can also know new FCM implementation.**